# Asynchronous callback in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I'm novice to jQuery, so please bear with me.*

I am struggling for making following to be called line-by-line

```
    gvUsers.PerformCallback();  // 1 --> Perform call back (DevExpress grid)

    $("#frmUser").submit();   // 2 --> Submit form for processing

    var mainElement = gvUsers.GetMainElement();
    var x = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteX(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetWidth() - 500) / 2;
    var y = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteY(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetHeight() - 200) / 2;

    reminderPopup.ShowAtPos(x, y); // 3 --> Show popup after processing
```

### What I tried so far?

**(1)** jQuery callback mechanism

```
    gvUsers.PerformCallback(function () // 1 --> Perform call back for passing selected keys
        {
            $("#frmUser").submit(function () // 2 --> Submit form for processing
            {
                var mainElement = gvUsers.GetMainElement();
                var x = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteX(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetWidth() - 500) / 2;
                var y = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteY(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetHeight() - 200) / 2;

                reminderPopup.ShowAtPos(x, y); // 3 --> Show popup with submitted data
            });
        });
```

And failed to make it work.

**(2)** Chaining by when and then

```
$.when(gvUsers.PerformCallback()).then($("#frmUser").submit()).then(function(){var mainElement = gvUsers.GetMainElement();
            var x = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteX(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetWidth() - 500) / 2;
            var y = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteY(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetHeight() - 200) / 2;

            reminderPopup.ShowAtPos(x, y);
        });
```

Once again failed.

***Can you please guide me to execute these three steps one after another in sequence?***

Answer (score 0):

In your first approach, the function you pass to the submit will be called immediately, it is not a success callback. you should read the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) in jquery.

you could try this, Im not sure this will work though:

```
// run this when form submitted
$("#frmUser").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
   var mainElement = gvUsers.GetMainElement();
   var x = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteX(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetWidth() - 500) / 2;
   var y = ASPxClientUtils.GetAbsoluteY(mainElement) + (gvUsers.GetHeight() - 200) / 2;
   reminderPopup.ShowAtPos(x, y); 
});

gvUsers.PerformCallback($("#frmUser").submit);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried it and nothing happened.